# Add reference during project load within Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, reference, load, .net-assembly

There some assemblies (.dll) or cs files in a folder named D:\MyFolder. I have project in Visual Studio and I want to add assemblies from above folder into References and add CS files from above folder on project load. Is there such feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There maybe slight differences depending on the version of Visual Studio that you are using but to add any dll as a reference to your project, just right click the 'References' folder of your project and then click the 'Browse' button in the Add References dialog.

This is the exact same procedure for adding a cs file to your project.  Right click your project, click Add, click Existing Item and then find your cs file from the file dialog and press OK.

UPDATE: There is no automatic way to point to a folder and have all files and or references in that folder added.  You can do a multi select of dll's or cs files in either dialog so that way you can multiple files.

Comment: I mean automatic feature :)